# Can't get x axis label to display in R qplot

Tags: macos, r, ggplot2

Try as I might, I can't seem to get qplot to print an x axis label when using facets. Reproducible toy example (requires diamonds dataset which I think comes with ggplot2):

```
dsmall <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 100), ]
qplot(color,price,data=dsmall ,facets=cut~.,xlab="TEST")
```

How do I add an x axis label to this?

Comment: Reproducible example? Can you `dput()` the data used or make up some dummy data?

Comment: Well that works for me., I get a bog fat "TEST" on the x-axis. Perhaps you could add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your Q. Are you running an up-to-date version of **ggplot2**?

Comment: Your updated code works well, i.e. the `xlab` gets displayed correctly.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing -- seems like no one else has the issue. Let me completely reinstall R on my Mac and try again (wonder if it's a Mac-only issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the window (just make it a hair smaller by clicking on the lower right corner and dragging a bit) or save the plot as a PDF to see the x axis label.

I think this may be a bug in the Mac version of R. Maybe a Lion issue with its fancier windows? Doesn't seem like anyone else is noticing this problem. Would be nice to get confirmation from someone else using the [Mac R64 binary 2.15.0](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) with ggplot2 0.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.4, and I'll submit a bug report.

Before resizing the Quartz window:
[image: plot with no apparent x axis label]
After resizing, the label magically appears:
[image: plot with x axis label]

Comment: I had this issue too.  If you go into Preferences -> Quartz you should see an option to "Override R Quartz width/height parameters".  If you check that and restart R the problem might go away.  At least it fixes that issue on my system.